# How/where to set breakpoints in NextJS app?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, next.js

I'm using nextjs, but can't figure out how or where to set breakpoints in the browser.

Using Chrome dev tools, when I expand the sv.moxne.net (my dev domain) I see what looks like compiled assets, not source assets.

[image: Chrome dev tools]

When I look under `webpack://` I can see a folder structure that resembles my source tree, however expanding it reveals 2 of every file. Each have different hashes in the name.

This is quite foreign to me. I've never run into this with SSR-enabled react apps in the past.

How do I know where to set breakpoints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have two options:

1. In the Sources pane of devtools, press CTRL-P and write the name of the file you want to debug, if you have two versions choose the one with [sm] at the end to see the original code you wrote. Add your breakpoint and refresh the page
2. Inside your file, add the keyword `debugger` before the line you want to debug

`someCode();
debugger
theCodeIWantToDebug();`

Answer (score 0):

To attach your VS code instance to your process and set breakpoints in your source files without the `debugger` keyword you can place this configuration in `/.vscode/launch.json`

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug server-side",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "command": "npm run dev"
    },
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug client-side",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000"
    },
    {
      "name": "Next.js: debug full stack",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "request": "launch",
      "command": "npm run dev",
      "serverReadyAction": {
        "pattern": "- Local:.+(https?://.+)",
        "uriFormat": "%s",
        "action": "debugWithChrome"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Granted, I can't confirm this works on the version you were using back when you asked the question - but today it works for me.

After adding this you can go to **Run and Debug** *(Ctrl + Shift + D)* in VS Code and run from there. Or press *F5* once you have selected your desired configuration.

Disclaimer: I can't remember where I got this from but I believe it  was somewhere in the next.js docs